# Can someone explain the difference in openssl cli and c++ DES output

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, des

Using openSSL, a program of mine is producing different encrypted output than openSSL's command line utility.  Using 'aaaaaa' as plain text and 'A' as the key, I've been running

```
openssl enc -des -e -nosalt -in test1.txt -out test1out.txt
```

to get a sample encryption, but my sample program (http://pastebin.com/e4P0DGYR) never produces the same hash.

To run the sample program, enter

```
./a.out 40 42 $(hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' test1.txt) $(hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' test1out.txt)
```

I used this (http://www.codealias.info/technotes/des_encryption_using_openssl_a_simple_example) as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone answered when you posted this on the openssl-users mailing list, the CLI uses ECB mode and the program uses CFB mode. DES-ECB isn't the same as DEC-CFB (or any other mode).

Comment: Actually `-des` on commandline is CBC not ECB; *both* differ from CFB64. Plus commandline `enc` normally does *password-based* encryption: the "key" you type (or specify with `-k` or `-kfile`) is run through a PKCS#5v1-ish computation to produce the actual key *and IV*; only `-K` (capital) specifies an actual key in hex. This is all on the manpage. Also the linked code can't be right: it tries to use keys from argv[0] to argv[1] (presumably but not standardly little-endian) while both the comments and the invocation above expect argv[1] to argv[2].

Comment: And this is why Stack Exchange is great.